# How to store user consent in an online database with Google User Messaging Platform(UMP) in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, gdprconsentform, user-messaging-platform

According to [Article 7(1)](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-7-gdpr/) of the GDPR:
"Where processing is based on consent, the controller shall be able to demonstrate that the data subject has consented to processing of his or her personal data."

This means that data controllers must record consent somewhere online in order to demonstrate that the user has consented.

According to the conversation [here](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/7YwBh6oOX0w/m/DqqM4uZ1AAAJ):
The user consent is stored in TCF string in SharedPreferences in Android and based on that string the appropriate ads(personalized/non-personalized) are served.

This means that the consent is stored locally and there is no way to access that information online.

I have used the code in these [docs](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/privacy) for unity.

How do I store the consent in an online database with the UMP?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.